# Display only selected record in magento form grid

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, grid

I want to display only those record that is selected or match with db record on load.
Untill i reset filter when reset filter it should show all record.

This is my grid.php code. I tried with `_addColumnFilterToCollection` function but not working.

```
    <?php
class Shipping_Shippinggroup_Block_Adminhtml_Shippinggroup_Edit_Tab_Formcustomer extends  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('customerGrid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true); // Using ajax grid is important
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);  //Dont save paramters in session or else it creates problems
        $this->setAdditionalJavaScript("
        // added click on selectbox support
        serializerController.prototype.rowClick = serializerController.prototype.rowClick.wrap(function(o, grid, event) {
            var tagName = Event.element(event).tagName
                isSelect = (tagName == 'SELECT' || tagName == 'OPTION');
            if (!isSelect) {
                o(grid, event);
            }
        });
        ");

    }



    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
{

    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $groupId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addNameToSelect()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('group_id',array('in' => array(5)));
     $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( array('shippinggroupcustomer'=> 'shippinggroupcustomer'), 'shippinggroupcustomer.customer_ids = e.entity_id and shippinggroupcustomer.shippinggroup_id='.$groupId,array('shippinggroup_id','customer_ids','shouldsendwarrantymail','shouldsendfactorymail','shouldsendordermail'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}



    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('customer_ids', array(
            'header_css_class'  => 'a-center',
            'type'              => 'checkbox',
            'name'              => 'customer_ids',
            'values'            => array_keys($this->_getSelectedCustomers()),
            'align'             => 'center',
            'index'             => 'entity_id'
        ));

         $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
            'index'     => 'name'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'email'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('shouldsendwarrantymail', array(
            'name'              => 'shouldsendwarrantymail',
            'index'             => 'shouldsendwarrantymail',
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Should Send Warranty Mail'),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'options'   => array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,


        ));

        $this->addColumn('shouldsendfactorymail', array(
            'name'              => 'shouldsendfactorymail',
            'index'             => 'shouldsendfactorymail',
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Should Send Factory Mail'),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'options'   => array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false


        ));
        $this->addColumn('shouldsendordermail', array(
            'name'              => 'shouldsendordermail',
            'index'             => 'shouldsendordermail',
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Should Send Order Mail'),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'options'   => array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false


        ));





        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row) {
        return false;
    }

    protected function _getSelectedCustomers()   // Used in grid to return selected customers values.
    {
        $customers = $this->getSelectedCustomers();
        return $customers;
    }

    public function getSelectedCustomers()
    {
        // Customer Data

        $tm_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        if(!isset($tm_id)) {
            $tm_id = 0;
        }

            $custIds = array();
            $customerProductIds = Mage::getModel('shippinggroup/shippinggroupcustomer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('shippinggroup_id', array(
                     array('finset' => $tm_id)));
                    // print_r($customerProductIds->getData());
            foreach($customerProductIds as $id){
                $custIds[$id->getCustomerIds()] = array(
                                                        'shouldsendwarrantymail' => $id->getShouldsendwarrantymail(),
                                                        'shouldsendfactorymail' => $id->getShouldsendfactorymail(),
                                                        'shouldsendordermail' => $id->getshouldsendordermail(),
                                                        );
            }

        //var_dump($custIds);exit;
        return $custIds;
    }

    /**
     * Rerieve grid URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/customergrid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok got the solution myself.

**Grid file changes**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('customerGrid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true); // Using ajax grid is important
    $this->setDefaultSort('id');
    $this->setDefaultFilter(array('customer_ids'=>1)); /* added this line to call column filter functino */
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);  //Dont save paramters in session or else it creates problems
    $this->setAdditionalJavaScript("
    // added click on selectbox support
    serializerController.prototype.rowClick = serializerController.prototype.rowClick.wrap(function(o, grid, event) {
        var tagName = Event.element(event).tagName
            isSelect = (tagName == 'SELECT' || tagName == 'OPTION');
        if (!isSelect) {
            o(grid, event);
        }
    });
    ");

}


 protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    // Set custom filter for in product flag
    if ($column->getId() == 'customer_ids') {
        $customersIds = array_keys($this->_getSelectedCustomers()); /* have multidimentional array so just need to pass customer_ids array */
        if (empty($customersIds)) {
            $customersIds = 0;
        }
        if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$customersIds));
        } else {
            if($customersIds) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin'=>$customersIds));
            }
        }
    } else {
        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }
    return $this;

}
```

Comment: very unclear what you did

Comment: Just added `$this->setDefaultFilter(array('customer_ids'=>1));` and it will call `_addColumnFilterToCollection` function to make selected